# How to overload '+' operator for this case,

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2005

i am trying to overload the + operator due to this error:

> tools.cpp(147) : error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which
>   takes a right-hand operand of type 'CSchemaString' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

The code is:

```
// I TRIED THIS TO OVERLOAD + OPERATOR
CSchemaString operator +(const CVisuComm& CVisuComm::TabCCUImess, 
                         const CSchemaString&       GetPriority);

//THE CODE AT WHICH THE ERROR IS RETURNED, 
//error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes 
//a right-hand operand of type 
//'CSchemaString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
CVisuComm::TabCCUImess[CVisuComm::nbCCUImess++]=
                        "RECONFIGURATION SOLUTION N° " +config.GetPriority();

//THE VARIOUS TYPES ARE
//CVisuComm-------class CVisuComm
//TabCCUImess-----static CString 
//nbCCUImess------static int nbCCUImess
//config----------CConfig_State_ChangeType 
//GetPriority-----CSchemaString
```

but it throws the same error along with

> error C2751: 'CVisuComm::TabCCUImess' : the name of a function
>   parameter cannot be qualified

So please suggest the correct way to overload the operator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve the formatting and organization.

Answer (score 0):

The second error message gives you a clue: `the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified`

You first parameter name should just be a name.  At the moment it is qualified with a class name.

Instead of: `const CVisuComm& CVisuComm::TabCCUImess`

maybe it should be: `const CVisuComm& Comm`